# Bash - Compound if statement

Tags: bash

I am trying to install NPM dependencies, if the directory does not exist, but this shorthand is not working as is.

```
    cd $(dirname "$0")
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-runtime" ]] && npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-es2015" ]] && npm install babel-preset-es2015
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-es2016" ]] && npm install babel-preset-es2016
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-polyfill" ]] && npm install babel-polyfill
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-stage-0" ]] && npm install babel-preset-stage-0
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-stage-1" ]] && npm install babel-preset-stage-1
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-stage-2" ]] && npm install babel-preset-stage-2
    if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-preset-stage-3" ]] && npm install babel-preset-stage-3
```

There is a syntax error - Bash expects a "then" - how can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the *if* construct in any of those lines,

```
[[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-runtime" ]] && npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

is just fine. Because you are operating based on the *return codes* of the `test` operator with `&&`, the `if..then` clause is not needed here. If you are still interested in having the `if` clause, you can do it using the classic way as

```
if [[ ! -d "node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-runtime" ]]; then
    npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime
fi
```

---

And as often [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) would have caught your problem right away!